# Title on three lines to a table

Tags: tables

I have a title typeset on three lines using the `center` environment. The vertical spacing between the lines looks really bad.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\usepackage{makecell}


\begin{document}


\begin{center}{\bfseries{Average Number of Video}}\end{center}
\begin{center}{\bfseries{Rentals Per Premium Member}}\end{center}
\begin{center}{\bfseries{at Store \textit{B}}}\end{center}
\smallskip

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tabular}{|| c !{\vrule width0.8pt} c | c | c||} \hline
    Year                &   1985    &   1986    &   1987 \\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
    Rentals             &   12      &   15      &   20 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\hspace{\fill}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you need three `center`s? One is enough! You can even use none

Comment: I want the title centered over the table.

Comment: I am sure that using the `center` environment to typeset the title for a table is not the appropriate format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is never a good idea to make captions bold.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption*{Average Number of Video\\Rentals Per Premium Member\\at Store \textit{B}}
\begin{tabular}{|| c !{\vrule width0.8pt} c | c | c||} \hline
    Year                &   1985    &   1986    &   1987 \\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
    Rentals             &   12      &   15      &   20 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The interline spacing in the title is quite nice.

Comment: I want to decrease the distance between the last line in the title and the top of the table.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire The spacing is nice because it is supposed to be nice. Btw I fixed the distance between the caption and the table

Comment: I didn't know that `usepackage` had options.

Comment: I replaced `[skip=0pt]` to `[skip=3pt]`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire But it does. `\usepackage` has options like `\documentclass` - who forbids it :)